# Get row id from database using checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, checkbox

I'm trying to delete a row from my MS access database using checkboxes. I have the database outputted to my JSP page, each row has a checkbox. I'm having trouble getting the rowId and also linking each checkbox with a row. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>

<html>
<head>
<title>DELETE Operation</title>
<script>
     checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName("input"); 

     for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
         var checkbox = checkboxes[i];
         checkbox.onclick = function() {
             var currentRow = this.parentNode.parentNode;
             var secondColumn = currentRow.getElementsByTagName("td")[1];

             alert("My text is: " + secondColumn.textContent );
         };
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<sql:setDataSource
    var = "bookdB"
    scope = "session"
    driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver"
    url = "jdbc:odbc:bookdB"
/>

<c:set var="empId" value="103"/>

<sql:update dataSource="${bookdB}" var="count">
  DELETE FROM Employees WHERE Id = ?
  <sql:param value="${empId}" />
</sql:update>

<sql:query dataSource="${bookdB}" var="result">
   SELECT * from Employees;
</sql:query>

<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
   <th></th>
   <th>Emp ID</th>
   <th>First Name</th>
   <th>Last Name</th>
   <th>Age</th>
</tr>

<c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
<form method="post" action="reserve.jsp">
<tr>
   <td><input type = "checkbox" value="reserve"></td>
   <td><c:out value="${row.id}"/></td>
   <td><c:out value="${row.first}"/></td>
   <td><c:out value="${row.last}"/></td>
   <td><c:out value="${row.age}"/></td>
</tr>
</form>
</c:forEach>
<input type = "submit" value="Delete">
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: MS access database screenshot]

[image: image 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my guess is correct you want to check the row(rows) and delete it from UI as well database.
Removing table row from UI is much easier work. First you need to set the id (must be unique) to each row(In your case probably emp id). Like this,

```
<table>
<tr id="${row.id}">
    <td><input type = "checkbox" value="${row.id}"></td>
    <td><c:out value="${row.id}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${row.first}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${row.last}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${row.age}"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="delete" onclick="deleteEmployee('${row.id}');" />
```

Here note that i am not going to refresh the page for deletting purpose.

in scripting side,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function deleteEmployee(rowid){
input_box = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this Record?");
if (input_box == true) {
    // Output when OK is clicked
    $.ajax({
    url : 'ur_ajax_url_for_delete'+rowid,
    type : "POST",
    async : false,
    success : function() {
        $('#' + rowid).remove();
        alert('Record Deleted');
    }
       });

return false;
} else {
    // Output when Cancel is clicked
    return false;
}
  }
</script>
```

Let me know if this helps. You have to implement your programming logic in ajax url for deleting the selected record.

**Updated :**
If you are looking for select many checkboxes and want to delete at single shot,
You need to get all checked checkboxes value by using javascript. Like this,
In html use name attribute for checkbox

```
<input type = "checkbox" value="${row.id}" name="empIds">
```

In scripting side,

```
var empIds = [];
$('#empIds > :selected').each(function() {
empIds.push($(this).val());
});
```

Use this empIds in ajax url instead of rowId. 
**PS** you need to get these values by using either Integer/String array in java.

**Screen shot** for firebug console
[image: Firebug inspecting console]

Comment: Hi Vinoth. Thanks, this did help a lot. I made the changes you suggested, but I'm still not able to delete the record. After the delete confirmation pops up, and I select 'Yes'. The record is still there.

Comment: Have you find any javascript error in your console? If so fix that. Also do find whether the row id has been set to each rows.

Comment: `$('#' + rowid).remove();` this will only happen when your ajax response is true. So check your java code whether the row gets deleted or not.

Comment: I'm not getting any javascript errors. I can't tell whether the row id has been set to each row. How would I do that?

Comment: The row doesn't get deleted

Comment: I uploaded a screenshot of my database, if that helps.

Comment: Check using tools like firebug.

Comment: I tested it. It does find the row id. see uploaded image 2

Comment: Your row id should not consists of #. Remove it from your code.

Comment: Yep, its removed. What do I add into the line                        | url : 'ur_ajax_url_for_delete'+rowid, | Whats the ajax url?

Comment: That is your servlet/jsp url (may be in your case `'reserve.jsp?empId='+rowid`)

Comment: Thanks for the help Vinoth. I still can't delete a record, but I appreciate your time. You definitely got me a lot closer to solving it.

Comment: You are welcome. Your upvote or accept as answer may help this post to be useful to others.